# Characterization of positive operators below an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T\in B(H)$ be positive. Is there a way to characterize all positive $S$ such that $S\leq T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose that $S,T\in B(H)$ with $T\geq0$. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. there exists a contraction $R$ such that  $S^{1/2}=RT^{1/2}=T^{1/2}R^*$;
> 2. There exists a contraction $R$ such that $RT^{1/2}=T^{1/2}R^*$ and $S=RTR^*$
> 3. there exists a contraction $R$ such that $S=T^{1/2}R^*RT^{1/2}$
> 4. $0\leq S\leq T$.

*Proof.* The implication 1$\implies$2 is simply $$S=S^{1/2}S^{1/2}=RT^{1/2}T^{1/2}R^*=RTR^*.$$

2$\implies$3. We have 
$$
S=RT^{1/2}T^{1/2}R^*=T^{1/2}R^*RT^{1/2}.
$$

3$\implies$4. Since $R$ is a contraction, $$\langle R^*Rx,x\rangle=\|Rx\|^2\leq\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle,$$ so $R^*R\leq I$. Then 
$$
S=T^{1/2}R^*RT^{1/2}\leq T^{1/2}IT^{1/2}=T. 
$$

4$\implies$1. Note that $\ker S^{1/2}=\ker S$, $\ker T^{1/2}=\ker T$. If $x\in \ker T^{1/2}$, then 
$$\tag1
\|S^{1/2}x\|^2=\langle Sx,x\rangle\leq\langle Tx,x\rangle=\|T^{1/2}x\|^2=0.
$$
Thus $\ker T^{1/2}\subset \ker S^{1/2}$. Define $R$ on $T^{1/2}H$ by 
$$
R(T^{1/2}x)=S^{1/2}x.
$$
This is well-defined, because if $T^{1/2}x=T^{1/2}y$, then $S^{1/2}x=S^{1/2}y$ by $(1)$. Also,
$$
\|R(T^{1/2}x)\|^2=\|S^{1/2}x\|^2=\langle Sx,x\rangle\leq\langle Tx,x\rangle=\|T^{1/2}x\|^2, 
$$
so $\|R\|\leq 1$. So we may extend $R$ to $\overline{T^{1/2}H}=(\ker T^{1/2})^\perp=(\ker T)^\perp$. For $x\in\ker T$, we define $Rx=0$. Then $R\in B(H)$ is a contraction, and $RT^{1/2}=S^{1/2}$. 
As $S^{1/2}$ is selfadjoint, we get $RT^{1/2}=T^{1/2}R^*$.

Comment: What about the case when both $S,T>0$? It then follows that $R$ must be injective, but can we say more? For instance, can we say that $R$ is invertible?

Comment: If both $S,T$ are positive and invertible, then so are their square roots, and so $R^{1/2}=T^{-1/2}S^{1/2}$ is invertible.

Comment: That's right, but I was thinking about $S,T>0$ without being necessarily invertible (perhaps my notation is not standard).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. It is easy to construct an example where $S,T$ are diagonal and compact, and so is $R$. And a compact operator cannot be invertible.

Comment: That was exactly the type of situation I had in mind. I thus imagine there is nothing more to say on $R$ in this case other than it is injective.